# what's wrong with my coding here?

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpimd.png)

```
fruitList = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]
searchFor = "apple"

def findIndex(el,fruitList):
    wordIndex = None
    for(ind, el) in enumerate(fruitList):
        if el == searchFor:
            wordIndex = ind
    return wordIndex
print("the index corresponding to", searchFor, "is", wordIndex)
```

Question description:
the above code is an excise in my python class. What we are trying to get at is to print out all of the indexes of the words in the list. but somehow when I print it out, it says the name "wordIndex" is not defined. So I wonder why's wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

I am really appreciative of anyone who invests their invaluable time in answering my question!

Comment: Don't post code as image. Post it as code.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing the rule here. I am still having difficulties in formatting my answer. Thank you for your reminder!

Comment: Further inquiry: would you be kind to take a look at my coding and see what's wrong with it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference you should post code as text, not as an image. Click the {} icon in the editor.

You put `wordIndex = None` inside of the `findIndex` function. This is fine, but you must understand that when you do this `wordIndex` will only be visible to code that is also inside of `findIndex`.

You also have to call `findIndex` to run the code there i.e. write `findIndex(someVariable, someList)`. When you put `return wordIndex` that means the function call to findIndex will evaluate to the value of wordIndex.

A corrected version:

```
fruitList = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]
searchFor = "apple"

def findIndex(el, fruitList):
    wordIndex = None
    for (ind, el) in enumerate(fruitList):
        if el == searchFor:
            wordIndex = ind
    return wordIndex
print("the index corresponding to", searchFor, "is", findIndex("",fruitList))
```

Notice the call to findIndex in the last print statement.
`findIndex("",fruitList)` gets evaluated to become the value of wordIndex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But when I print my code out, its output is the index 1 If I want to print out all of the indexes of the words in the list, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Your question is too general. Sorry, I can't teach variable scope, functions, for loops, and arrays in a stackoverflow post. First understand how the each line of code you have now works, and then you will be able to try to come up with a solution to print all the indexes on your own. It may not work, but at least you'll have a specific example to ask questions about.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct (looking at the example you pasted).

```
fruitList = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]
searchFor = "apple"

def findIndex(el,fruitList):
    wordIndex = None
    for (ind, el) in enumerate(fruitList):
        if el == searchFor:
            wordIndex = ind

    return wordIndex
```

This code has no syntax errors.

But you probably want to pass searchFor as a parameter to your function:

```
fruitList = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]

def findIndex(element, list):
    wordIndex = None
    for (ind, el) in enumerate(fruitList):
        if el == element:
            wordIndex = ind

    return wordIndex

print(findIndex("banana", fruitList))
```

Be careful your function parameter names are independent of more-global variable names.  Otherwise it will give you problems with variable scope.  For example, in your findIndex() function, there is a 'fruitList' in global scope, but local scope (to the function) too.  The local scope takes precedence.